# Dynamically passing class name

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

```
<ul>
  <% @pages.situations.each do |situation| %>
    <li class="<%= situation %>">
      <%= image_tag('image/"<%situation%>".png') %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I want to pass the images name dynamically in rails. Basically, my lists, image and class names are the same so I tried to do like something above. It doesn't work. Would really appreciate your help guys. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpolation is not done correctly, try something like this

```
<%= image_tag("image/#{situation}.png") %>
```